# Reporting Services: Root element is missing

Tags: reporting-services

I downloaded a report in rdl format from the server (i couldnt find the original rdl from my hdd) and when i try to open it in Visual Studio i get an error:
Root element is missing

```
Root element is missing
```

And a link to Edit code, which does nothing when you click it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Open rdl file with a text editor like notepad. You will see a xml format. In BIDS you can add a rdl report in your report project, after that copy the xml content of the rdl file to code view of new rdl report.